# Decode JSON (String) - visual basic

Tags: json, vb.net

How can I decode a JSON String in Visual Basic (without download programs)

```
Private Sub ViewHintToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ViewHintToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim instance As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient
    Dim address As String = "https://pr2hub.com/files/artifact_hint.txt"
    Dim returnValue As String
    returnValue = instance.DownloadString(address)
    Artifact.Text = returnValue
    HintText.Show()
    HintText.RichTextBox1.Text = returnValue
    HintText.RichTextBox2.Text = returnValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VB.Net? What exactly do you want to do with this JSON?

Comment: You're retrieving a string (which is not encoded). Do you want to built an object based on that string? If you simple need to parse it for specific values, you can use standard string manipulations (Split, Substring etc.)

Comment: if you really want to go that route there is [JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864.aspx) though manually parsing it with string manipulations as @YuriyGalanter mentioned would be a lot easier.

Comment: I'd second the suggestion @RaphaelSmit gave.  If the JSON is well-formed and predictable, then just create a class around it, use the appropriate attributes to indicate what goes where, and deserialise it.  Or just parse the text.

Answer (score 0):

By Decode I am assuming you mean Deserialize.  Have you tried System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ?

I don't understand what you're trying to deserialize above but here's a generic example:

```
Dim s as String = "{ 'name':'Fred', 'address':'123 Main', 'phone':'333-4444'}"
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim o As Object = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(s)
```

Note there is also a jss.Serialize method available.